# sys.dm_db_partition_stats - incorrect row count for InMemory tables

Tags: sql-server, dmv, memory-optimized-tables

I have a problem with `sys.dm_db_partition_stats` DMV. When having InMemory tables (with hash indexes, columnstores, classical b-tree) and trying to get row count via this query there is 0 displayed for all InMemory ones:

```
WITH cte AS 
(
SELECT t.name as table_name,
       SUM(s.used_page_count) AS used_pages_count,
       SUM(CASE
            WHEN (i.index_id < 2) THEN (in_row_data_page_count + lob_used_page_count + row_overflow_used_page_count)
            ELSE lob_used_page_count + row_overflow_used_page_count
           END) AS pages,
       MAX(s.row_count) AS row_count  
  FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats s
  INNER JOIN sys.tables t 
          ON s.object_id = t.object_id
  INNER JOIN sys.indexes i 
          ON i.object_id = t.object_id 
         AND s.index_id = i.index_id
GROUP BY t.name
)
SELECT cte.table_name, 
       CAST((cte.pages * 8.)/1024 AS DECIMAL(10,3)) AS table_size_mb, 
       CAST(((CASE WHEN cte.used_pages_count > cte.pages 
                THEN cte.used_pages_count - cte.pages
                ELSE 0 
              END) * 8./1024) AS DECIMAL(10,3)) AS indexes_mb,
       cte.row_count
  FROM cte
ORDER BY 2 DESC
;
```

I know that space used by table and indexes for InMemory table cannot be get by this query, but the row count should work.

When you execute just:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
```

you can see that in row_count column is non-zero row count for all InMemory tables. Is there some bug in Microsoft SQL Server (I tried this on SQL2016SP1 and older versions)? Or am I doing something wrong? All InMemory tables I had created are not empty - so SELECT * displayed proper row count.

Another point - when you add filtering WHERE clause with table name or LIKE which filters InMemory tables only, non zero row count is also returned...

Answer (score 1):

Details about In-Memory Tables cannot always be seen using the "normal" dynamic management views, or DMVs, such as `sys.dm_db_partition_stats`.

Instead, you'll need to use the In-Memory views detailed on MSDN.

For instance, [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn205318.aspx) talks about how to calculate row and table size for In-Memory tables.

[MSSQLTips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3111/new-sql-server-2014-dynamic-management-views/) has a decent starting list of In-Memory related DMVs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know about InMemory-related DMVs, but still dont know why above mentioned view returns non-consistent information.